# Explanation of output for Naive bayes algorithm in R

Tags: r, output, prediction, naivebayes

I am new to Statistics and data analysis in R.
Today i was trying Naive Bayes algorithm in R. 
The problem i am facing is that I am unable to understand the output of the prediction. 
The code is followed like this:

`install.packages('ElemStatLearn')`
`library('ElemStatLearn')`

`library("klaR")
library("caret")`

```
sub = sample(nrow(spam), floor(nrow(spam) * 0.9))
```

`train = spam[sub,]`

`test = spam[-sub,]`

```
xTrain = train[,-58]
```

`yTrain = train$spam`

```
xTest = test[,-58]
```

`yTest = test$spam`

```
model = train(xTrain,yTrain,'nb',trControl=trainControl(method='cv',number=10)) 
prop.table(table(predict(model$finalModel,xTest)$class,yTest))`
```

Result display here is as follow:

```
   yTest
             email       spam
  email 0.33405640 0.02603037
  spam  0.24945770 0.39045553
```

Can refer this link to see http://joshwalters.com/2012/11/27/naive-bayes-classification-in-r.html

Answer (score 1):

The result that you have displayed is called a 'confusion matrix'. It is used to verify how well your classifier has worked.

You will need to understand a few terms here :-                                 True positive (TP), False positive (FP),True negative (TN) ,False negative (FN)

Compare :

[image]

with your case

[image]

The diagonal from left top to right bottom gives you the %age of right predictions, and the other two values indicate the %age that your classifier got "confused"

Hope this gives an initial idea. 
Google for confusion matrix and you can find more. 
One good link is here : https://classeval.wordpress.com/introduction/basic-evaluation-measures/

Answer (score 0):

It is not the naive bayes model's output.

Once you used predict, you don't really "care" about the model, because you already obtained the prediction.

`table.prop` creates the proportion out of each combination for the entire population. You might want to consider looking at the table without the proportion part, to see the actual numbers

For example 33.4% will be detected as email and will be actually an email, while 2.6% will be detected as email while they are actually spam.

Comment: Ok, Got it, the Naive Bayes Model output is stored in model data frame. But then what is the meaning of kappa and accuracy. @Shahar Bental

Comment: Can you share the code and output for kappa and accuracy?
Accuracy is well defined,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision

Cohen's Kappa is a form of "normalized" accuracy:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen's_kappa

Comment: Above written is my code, And Naive Bayes 
   4140 samples
   57 predictor
   2 classes: 'email', 'spam' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 3726, 3726, 3727, 3727, 3725, 3725, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  usekernel  Accuracy   Kappa    
  FALSE      0.7126367  0.4581488
   TRUE      0.5599037  0.2290060